# Why does `UserManager.ConfirmEmailAsync` throw for an invalid user?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

Given my code in `ConfirmEmail`:

```
var result = await UserManager.ConfirmEmailAsync(userId, code);
if (result.Succeeded)
{
    model.Message = "Thank you for confirming your email.";
    model.IsConfirmed = true;
    return View(model);
}
```

based closely on the code from the standard MVC 5 project template, I would expect an invalid user to cause `result.Succeeded == false`, not to have `ConfirmEmailAsync` throw an `InvalidOperationException`.

Comment: I agree with you. If the user is not found then we need to catch the exception and handle it gracefully ourselves since the framework doesn't.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The source code of `UserManager.ConfirmEmailAsync` is:

```
public virtual async Task<IdentityResult> ConfirmEmailAsync(TKey userId, string token)
{
    ThrowIfDisposed();
    var store = GetEmailStore();
    var user = await FindByIdAsync(userId).ConfigureAwait(false);
    if (user == null)
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException(String.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, Resources.UserIdNotFound, userId));
    }
    if (!await VerifyUserTokenAsync(userId, "Confirmation", token))
    {
        return IdentityResult.Failed(Resources.InvalidToken);
    }
    await store.SetEmailConfirmedAsync(user, true).ConfigureAwait(false);
    return await UpdateAsync(user).ConfigureAwait(false);
}
```

You can see that `InvalidOperationException` is thrown when user was not found using `FindByIdAsync(userId)`.

So this behaviour is by design.

Comment: Nice - The OP could always override this method to get his desired functionality.